# Chunked Parsing with FParsec

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

Is it possible to submit input to an FParsec parser in chunks, as from a socket? If not, is it possible to retrieve the current result and unparsed portion of an input stream so that I might accomplish this? I'm trying to run the chunks of input coming in from `SocketAsyncEventArgs` without buffering entire messages.

**Update**

The reason for noting the use of `SocketAsyncEventArgs` was to denote that sending data to a `CharStream` might result in asynchronous access to the underlying `Stream`. Specifically, I'm looking at using a circular buffer to push the data coming in from the socket. I remember the FParsec documentation noting that the underlying `Stream` should not be accessed asynchronously, so I had planned on manually controlling the chunked parsing.

Ultimate questions:

1. Can I use a circular buffer under my `Stream` passed to the `CharStream`?
2. Do I not need to worry myself with manually controlling the chunking in this scenario?

Comment: FParsec works on CharStream, so the answer is probably yes. I will defer to better answers (hopefully) though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normal version of FParsec (though not the [Low-Trust version](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/download-and-installation.html#low-trust-version)) reads the input chunk-wise, or "block-wise", as I call it in the [`CharStream` documentation](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charstream.html#CharStream.remarks). Thus, if you construct a `CharStream` from a `System.IO.Stream` and the content is large enough to span multiple `CharStream` blocks, you can start parsing before you've fully retrieved the input.

Note however, that the `CharStream` will consume the input stream in chunks of a fixed (but configurable) size, i.e. it will call the `Read` method of the `System.IO.Stream` as often as is necessary to fill a complete block. Hence, if you parse the input faster than you can retrieve new input, the `CharStream` may block even though there is already some unparsed input, because there's not yet enough input to fill a complete block.

**Update**

The answer(s) to your ultimate questions: <s>42.</s>

- How you implement the `Stream` from which you construct the `CharStream` is entirely up to you. The restriction you're remembering that excludes parallel access only applies to the `CharStream` class, which isn't thread safe.
- Implementing the `Stream` as a circular buffer will likely [restrict the maximum distance over which you can backtrack.](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charstream.html#CharStream.remarks.non-sequential-access)
- The block size of the `CharStream` influences how far you can backtrack when the `Stream` does not support seeking.
- The simplest way to parse input asynchronously is to do the parsing in an async task (i.e. on a background thread). In the task you could simply read the socket synchronously, or, if you don't trust the buffering by the OS, you could use a stream class like the `BlockingStream` described in the article you linked in the second comment below.
- If the input can be easily separated into independent chunks (e.g. lines for a line-based text format), it might be more efficient to chunk it up yourself and then parse the input chunk by chunk.

Comment: Thanks, Stephan. I revised my question to better reflect what I'm trying to better understand. I was initially excited about the `CharStream` approach, but the note I found previously about asynchronous access to the underlying `Stream` caused me to pause.

Comment: Would something like this work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163290.aspx

Comment: I've updated my reply. Does this answer your questions? I'm not sure which note regarding asynchrounous access to the underlying `Stream` you refer to exactly. Could you write where exactly you found that note?

Comment: I believe the note was in the old documentation. I can't find the reference in the new documentation. Thanks! This answers all of my questions. :)