# FParsec Reactive Example

Tags: f#, system.reactive, parser-combinators, fparsec

I'm hopeful that someone could potentially post an example of using FParsec where the data is based on some sort of incoming live stream.

Some examples could be producing a result based on mouse gestures, generating an alert or notification based on a specific sequence of stock ticks.

If someone could post an example it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This thread could be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891019/chunked-parsing-with-fparsec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Reactive Parsers](http://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parsers&referringTitle=Documentation) out of Rxx.

This isn't F# but rather a .NET library that let's you write code such as (following from your stock example):

```
    var alerts = ticks.Parse(parser =>
    from next in parser
    let ups = next.Where(tick => tick.Change > 0)
    let downs = next.Where(tick => tick.Change < 0)
    let downAlert = from manyUps in ups.AtLeast(2).ToList()
               from reversalDown in downs.NonGreedy()
               where reversalDown.Change <= -11
               select new StockAlert(manyUps, reversalDown)
    let upAlert = from manyDowns in downs.AtLeast(2).ToList()
            from reversalUp in ups.NonGreedy()
            where reversalUp.Change >= 21
            select new StockAlert(manyDowns, reversalUp)
    select downAlert.Or(upAlert).Ambiguous(untilCount: 1));
```

Credit of course goes to Dave Sexton and James Miles who did the majority of this work.

For background reading, the parser extensions to Rxx came out of this discussion: http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/rx/thread/0f72e5c0-1476-4969-92da-633000346d0d

Here's a very simple example of how this could be used in F#:

```
open Rxx.Parsers.Reactive
open Rxx.Parsers.Reactive.Linq

// F# shortcuts to Rxx
let where f (a:IObservableParser<_,_>) = a.Where(fun b -> f b)
let toList (parser:IObservableParser<_,_>) = parser.ToList()
let (<&>) (a:IObservableParser<'a,'b>) (b:IObservableParser<'a,'b>) = a.And(b)
let create a = 
    { new ObservableParser<_,_>() with
        override x.Start = a(x.Next) } :> IObservableParser<_,_>
let parse (parser:IObservableParser<_,_>) (obs:IObservable<_>) = obs.Parse(parser)

// example of grammar
let grammar = 
    (fun (parser:IObservableParser<_,_>) ->
        let next = parser.Next
        let bigs = next |> where(fun i -> i > 25)
        let smalls = next |> where(fun i -> i <= 25)
        bigs <&> smalls |> toList ) 
    |> create

// the test
let random = Random()
let values = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0)).Select( fun _ -> random.Next(1,50)).Trace().TraceSubscriptions("subbing","subbed","disposing","disposed").Publish()

let sub = values |> parse grammar |> Observable.add(printfn "BIG THEN SMALL: %A")
let test = values.Connect()
```